# How do I update the value of a complex object within another object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given the following two classes, which are representing tables in a database, I want to set the statustype of MyClass to one of the two predefined values that are in the StatusType DB.

```
 public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual StatusType StatusType { get; set; }
   }

 public class StatusType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyClass> MyClasses{ get; set; }
    DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

There is a third table (MyClass_StatusType) that is not represented by an entity that acts as a many to one intermediary.

My code:

```
      MyClass mc = new MyClass();
      mc.Description = "Description";
      mc.StatusType.Id = 3;
      db.MyClasses.Add(mc);
      var id = db.SaveChanges();
```

There is a record in my StatusType with an ID of 3. When I run this code I get a null reference exception on the StatusType.

What is the correct way to set this value in MyClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the exception because of the access to StatusType in this line

```
mc.StatusType.Id = 3;
```

mc is a new object and has no StatusType defined.

**1)** The best way to correct this is to use the FK field StatusTypeId

```
mc.StatusTypeId = 3;
```

**2)** But if you can't use this field the other solution is the following:

You should instead of setting the Id (of an non existing StatusType) set it to the existing type. This makes a extra roundtrip to the DB to get the StatusType object.

```
var statusType = MyMethodToGetExistingStatusType(3);
mc.StatusType = statusType;
```

I don't know how you can get your instance of your Type but in the method **MyMethodToGetExistingStatusType()** you can handle this.

I hope this helps you?

Comment: You are ignoring the EF FK Convention here which causes you to have an extra trip to SQL database and much more code. The `MyMethodToGetExistingStatusType(3)` is not needed at all.

Comment: Yes that's right that the MyMethodToGetExistingStatusType() method is not needed at all, but it was only for clarification that he can get there his object.
You are correct. If he would have had the FK I would also have suggested to use the FK, but for some reason he didn't have this FK.
I will add this to my answer to make it clear for others.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your FK in the MyClass class. If you add

```
 Public int StatusTypeId {get;set;}
```

This maps a FK for your entity. Currently you only have a navigation property.

Then rather than doing

```
  mc.StatusType.Id = 3
```

You just do

```
  mc.StatusTypeId = 3
```

This will save you from having to select from the `StatusType` table. Meaning a lot less code and one less trip to your SQL server.